# Any book reader app that can open a web-page?

Tags: android, html, ebooks

Reading an eBook in MoonReader is really joyful. Long HTML article are simllar to books. Is there any book reader apps that can open a web page directly?

Comment: u meant within a web browser or the app itself should contain a integrated browser?

Comment: @BlueBerry-vignesh4303 I mean it should open it like an ebook. Have you see the style of showing ebook on such software? You do not need to scroll, they will show it in tiny pages and keep reading progress.

Comment: I don't know of any eBook reader having that option. But what comes close to it is "Pocket" (formerly known as "Reat it Later"). Their app "reorganizes page content" in a way that makes it easier reading it on small devices. Not exactly what you're after, but IMHO still worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

https://getpocket.com is good indeed and it can read the pages via a decent voice generator, although the interface for it is clunky.

IMO Pocket is too often not able to process an article right. I can compare to [Firefox read mode](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/view-articles-reader-view-firefox-android), which handles almost any text correctly, is pleasure to use but lacks the ability to store the location that you have reached so far.

Other way is to [convert the page](https://dotepub.com/converter/?lang=en) to .epub or .pdf and read it as usually.